# Heap size getting increased while working with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

In libgdx I used to release all resources such as textures, audio resources and also world object.As I have lot textures, drawbles in my game. Managing with textures and sound resources has been released by calling dispose(). But the problem still recurring and heap size is getting increased. Possibly at a certain point VM can not allocate the memory for process if it exceeds maximum size, finally result is **OutOfMemory**. Please help me to come out from this.App flow

1. Home Activity renders to another Activity which extends AndroidApplication(application listener).
2. In that i am calling application listener in onCreate() by initializing listener here.
3. Passing some game data to listener along with context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Bitmap class, then you might want to check that you are calling recycle on each one before disposing.  This fixed many of my memory problems.

Docs on Bitmap and recycle() can be found here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

If that doesn't help then you are going to have to describe a bit more how the application is structured.  Perhaps you have errant threads or something that are eating up resources.  What tools are you using to diagnose your memory issues?

Comment: i am loading texture into my game as "new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("top.png"));". I am not using bitmap class here. externally i am using libgdx framwork only and in dispose() i am calling texture.dispose().

Comment: Have you tried using MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyze a few dumps and see what is eating up the most space?  There is some interesting things to be found by going though them. 

Does the memory increase constantly, when the activity is paused and resumed, or by some action in your application?

Comment: I am going to have look into it

Comment: I observed that some of float[], char[] are consuming much level by level. Even i am releasing resources properly, unable to manage it

Comment: I have Edited the post and described control flow of my game, as I told when player wins or pauses or else lost the game, I am raising other Activity and destroying that application in onDestroy(). FYI even I pause, resume or lost and for next level it is being increased at every case.

Comment: Since you are doing some activity creation and destroying and it is leaking you  might want to read this article from google on context leaking.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Essentially if you need to keep long-lived drawables use the application context, if not then make absolutely sure that the activity context is not being held in memory or all (which can be achieved accidently by holding a resource related to that context).